# Python: Read database to display table with equal columns

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have a program when it currently reads from a database, which can be found [here](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Applied_Programming/Databases/Northwind_SQL). I have users choose a specific record they want to display so the SQL command will execute that record. Now I have a table that currently displays those records, however, the columns are not how I wanted to look because I am dealing with long strings of data.

I am not using any extended libraries. My table display is sort of equal for some tables except tables like Suppliers, Orders, Categories. The width for each column is way too long. It takes too much space.

I think my code currently takes the longest string from the whole table and set the width of that for each column. What I want it to do instead is to take the longest string for each column and NOT the whole table, so the width of each column is set by string length (with like a little extra space of course) of that column.

Here is my code so far:

```
import sqlite3

def read_display(record):
  database = 'data.db'
  connection = sqlite3.connect(database)
  c = connection.cursor()
  # selects a table to display
  sql = "SELECT * FROM {0}".format(record)
  cursor.execute(sql)
  conn.commit()
  results = cursor.fetchall()

  header = [i[0] for i in c.description]
  data = [header] + list(tuple(results))
  width = max((len(str(x)) for d in data for x in d))

  for i, d in enumerate(data):
      line = ' | '.join(str(x).ljust(width) for x in d)
      print(line)
      if i == 0:
         print('-' * len(line))
```

I tried to mess with the `width` variable, but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried looking at other StackOverflow q's but they are dealing with little data, so it is easier to set the width. This data contains huge strings.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Comment**: what does `_` mean in *#2*?

Read [What is the purpose of the single underscore “_” variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/7414759)
Here, **"3. As a general purpose "throwaway" variable name"**, we don't need the `range(...` value.

---

> **Question**: display database records as table with equal columns

1. Get the columns names and prepend it to the `results`.

   ```
       header = tuple(i[0] for i in cur.description)
       data = [header] + results
   ```
2. Init `config` as a `list` with `{'width':0}`.
   Create as many `dict` items as columns in the database table.

   ```
       config = [{'width':0} for _ in range(len(data[0]))]
   ```
3. Loop the **whole** data, which is `list` of `tuple`.
   Find the `max len` and store it in the columns `config dict`

   ```
       for rec in data:
           for c, value in enumerate(rec):
               config[c]['width'] = max(config[c]['width'], len(str(value)))
   ```
4. Prepare `format list`, using the `width` from `config`

   ```
       format_ = []
       for f in config:
           format_.append('{:<' + str(f['width']) + '}')
   ```
5. Convert the `list format_` to `str` using a `'|'` as delimiter.

   ```
       format_ = ' | '.join(format_)
   ```
6. Loop the `data`, `list` of `tuple`, print using the `format_` string.

   ```
       for rec in data:
           print(format_.format(*rec))
   ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: I am trying to follow, do you happen to have a repl example of the full code for this?

Comment: It's a full working example, replace your Questions code starting with line `header = `

Comment: what does _ mean in #2? Can that be any name/variable or no?

Comment: @smokingpenguin: Updated my answer. Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)